# $C=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}\in R^2: x_1>1$ and $ x_2\ge x_1$ prove/disprove it is open/closed

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, solution-verification

**$C=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}\in R^2: x_1>1$ and $ x_2\ge x_1$ show and prove whether this is open or closed set**

My guess was that this was not open and closed. When I tried to visualize it, it appears to be basically an y=x graph with the left side elements of the set as long as x is greater than 1

*Let's start by inspecting whether or not it's open:*

To be open, there exists for all $a$ the ball $B(a,r)$ where a is the centre and r is the radius of the ball. By inspection, pick point a such that $x_1=x_2$, then for any radius $r>0$, it does not fit within the set

**Now I'm kinda not confident about this line of reasoning and it's pretty hand-wavy and probably even opposite from true**

*Now onto inspecting whether it's closed*:

I'm guessing it's closed since all of its frontier points are in the set, (well except for when x1=0?)

Comment: Consider the point $(1,1)$. Of interest also are points of the form $(x,x)$ $x>1$.

Comment: You're on the right track re open and can clean up your reasoning quite easily.  Consider the point $a=(x, x)$ and place a ball $B(a, r)$ around that point.  Then the point $b=(x+ \frac r2, x) \in B(a, r)$ but $b \notin C$, so $B(a, r) \not \subseteq C$.  Since $r \gt 0$ is arbitrary, what conclusion can you draw?  What definition of closed are you using?

Comment: @RobertShore I guess I could use the same logic to demonstrate or disprove whether the complement is also not-closed/closed to prove if the set itself is closed or not

Comment: Yes.  You should conclude (by noting that $(1, 1) \notin C$) that $C$ is not closed either.

Comment: Just as a general guideline for these sorts of problems: Strict inequalities ("$<$") mean that any boundary points resulting from that inequality are not in the set. Non-strict inequalities ("$\le$") mean that any corresponding boundary points are in the set. They are where the "$=$" part of the inequality holds. Open $\equiv$ no boundary points in the set, Closed $\equiv$ all boundary points in the set. These rules do not constitute a proof, but they do show you what points you should be looking at to determine the answer.